# Selenium automation undetectable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to massively create accounts on a website. I have everything automated in seleniun with python. the problem is that after creating approximately 5 accounts it detects me as a robot. I'd like to cover all the points so you don't find out what an automation is.

my tool does the following when I create an account:

- change the router's public ip
- change user agent
- I use a modified chromedriver so that it is detected as a normal chrome
- I delete cache, sessions, and cookies.

with this I believed that the web would never detect me as a robot. but I think I'm forgetting something.

thanks!

Comment: are you modifying your location? that might be a verification point

Comment: the page does not ask me for location. my public ip change by restarting the router. the location of my ip does not change. but if I create an account from another device if it lets me. so it's something strange that happens on my computer